# what is difference between environment variable types

Tags: openshift

I'm trying to use OpenShift.
I'm confusing between three writing ways:

```
${env.OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST}
${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST}
```

and

```
$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST
```

Could you show me what the difference between them is?

Comment: No difference. They all still point to the env var OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
${env.OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST}
```

is only applicable in standalone.xml for JBoss application.  env. references environment variables and ${} without env references system properties.  So

```
${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST}
```

in standalone.xml is referencing a system property.  In a bash script though it would be referencing the environment variable because OpenShift sources all env variables for cartridge scripts.  Likewise

```
$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST
```

is just another way to reference a variable in bash.  In bash $var and ${var} are interchangeable except when variable demarkation is an issue.  $varblah is not the same as ${var}blah for example.